# how to access a webapp deploy folder for deployed war, docker

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, geoserver

I have a docker container which extends `FROM tomcat:7.0.75-jre8`

It downloads `geoserver 2.10.2 war`, and deploys to `tomcat`. All is well... however... I need to access the deploy folder within tomcat's webapps folder in order to add extensions such as mysql db plugin, oracle db plugin oracle jdbc driver etc. this needs to happen automated within my dockerfile. This is fine with containerising a jetty style build... but with Tomcat its another matter.

In short, I need access to `WEB-INF`

When I build, I assume the webapps folder will not be created until my final line running `catalina.sh` is executed right? ie:

```
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I've tried running, then `/bin/bash` shelling into the image but the webapp folder does not exist. I must be missing something simple...?

Is there someway to force tomcat to generate the deploy webapp folder so i can access `WEB-INF` etc

**Edit2: patching of the war before deployment might be a solution.**

ie, Merely unzip the `war` file (you can just rename to zip, as its indeed a zip file). Then make all the modifications I need ie, jar plugin files into `/WEB-INF/lib`. Then re-zip, rename to .war extension and deploy as per normal.

Comment: You mean to say that external jar files needs to be copied ?

Comment: yes i need to copy in jar files. I've actually realised I could simply automate the steps of renaming the `war` > `zip`, unzip, make modifications, such as copying across jars into `/WEB-INF/libs`, re-zip and deploy... all should be good then